# Amazon Web Services Cloudwatch - Healthy Host Count of ELB show no data when ec2 is manually stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created ELB and 2 ec2 instances under that ELB in same zone. I have given simple healthcheck url of my application with port 8080 since application is deployed on tomcat which runs on default port 8080.
When I manually stop both ec2 instances then no data plotted in Healthy Host Count metric of ELB and Alarms which are created on this ELB HHC metric show Insufficient Data. ELB Itself show both servers out of service in Load Balancer console but cloudwatch metric doesn't show HHC where it was supposed to display 0.
Interestingly when instead of stopping ec2 instances if I stop only tomcat service on these instances then ELB cloudwatch metric is updated correctly and HHC goes to 0 and corresponding Alarm is also triggered. I was expecting same result when I manually stop ec2 instances as in both cases HealthCheck url is not accessible.
I have checked all HealthyHostCount metrics(zone wise and etc) in cloudwatch but all of them shows same result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to monitor whether the instances are down as well as when your application is down (tomcat)

If dropped traffic is your concern the ELB shouldn't send any traffic to the instance whether the application (in your case tomcat) is down or the instance is down.

If you want to get alerts/alarms when the instance is down I suggest you look at adding metrics to the instance rather than the ELB

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems right although ELB shouldn't send traffic to the instance in these two conditions for two different reasons... when the app is down, it's because of failed health-checks; stopping of instances appears to cause a different condition, by background communication between ELB and EC2 which may cause ELB to assume you intended the instance to be removed from the ELB by stopping it... in which case, the healthy host count is sort of undefined, since 0 running divided by 0 provisioned would be undefined; an ELB with no instances would would arguably have "NaN" (un)healthy instances.

Comment: Instances are not removed from ELB, in Load Balancer's dashboard, instances tab it shows 0 instances in Service out of 2.